# Bird droppings invalidating location for prayer?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, animals, bathroom

[One may not pray near feces](http://e.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=10573) or other sources of biological waste and decay that give a foul odor (see the article for several opinions on when/how it applies).  Does this include bird droppings?

I've never smelled a foul odor from them, but I imagine that if someone kept dozens of birds together in a house and didn't clean the house, that the build-up of droppings would smell, meaning that there is *some* foul smell.  And it *is* biological waste.

Does this mean that it falls into the same category as cow manure for purposes of the Halachah?

Comment: [tag:bathroom]? That's an impressively trained bird you have there!

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't want to create a new tag for "feces". I thought "bathroom" sufficed.

Comment: I agree. **:)**

Comment: BTW bolding punctuation is an _excellent_ way to get to 15 characters in a comment ***.***

Answer (score 5):

At the end of [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 79:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=224), the Mechaber writes with regards to a a bird's waste that one does not have to distance oneself from it if it doesn't stink, but if it does stink it has the same law as the waste of a person.

The Mishna Berura explains (S"K 22) that unless one knows for a fact the waste stinks he can assume it doesn't. He also (S"K 23) Defines stink as being so bad that a person is pained from it.

(Also see the S"K 24 regarding the Magen Avraham's leniency regarding the stink of birds' - and regular animals' - waste)

Answer (score 2):

The prohibition to pray near feces is only for feces that either smells bad, even if it doesn't come from a species whose poop normally smells bad; or if it comes from a species whose poop normally smells bad, even if it doesn't smell bad.

You aren't allowed to pray near the poop of turkeys and you're not allowed to pray near a chicken coop, but I think you're allowed to pray near the poop of chickens, since — as you mentioned — it usually doesn't smell bad.

Source: [Shulchan Aruch 79:5-8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=224) and MB there